# Full FastText model from KeyedVectors to infer new words in aligned space

Tags: nlp, gensim, fasttext

I am working on a NLP problem with gensim that requires the use of multilingual embeddings. I have the already pretrained and aligned .txt embeddings that [FastText provides in their web](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/aligned-vectors.html). Sadly, they don't provide the full model, but these vectors are missing some important vocabulary on my problem and the per-character embedding ability of a FastText model here comes very handy for these cases.

My question:

1. Is there a way to recreate the entire model so I can infer new vocabulary that is also in the vector space of aligned embeddings?
2. If not, Is there still a way to obtain those terms in that aligned embedding space? Without having to retrain a new entire FastText and then align it the already pre-trained ones?